# Is an $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-triple determined up to Lie algebra automorphism by the adjoint representation?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite-dimensional complex semisimple Lie algebra, and let $\phi_1:\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow\mathfrak{g}$ and $\phi_{2}:\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow\mathfrak{g}$ be complex Lie algebra morphisms. By composing $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ with the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{g}$, we obtain two representations of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ on $\mathfrak{g}$. My question is then the following.

**Question:** If these two $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$-representations are isomorphic, does it follow that $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are related by an element of the Lie algebra automorphism group $\text{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$?

To provide some context, suppose that $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{so}_{4n}(\mathbb{C})$. If $\lambda$ is a partition of $4n$ having only even parts with each part appearing an even number of times, then $\lambda$ corresponds to exactly two distinct nilpotent orbits, $\mathcal{O}_1$ and $\mathcal{O}_2$, in $\mathfrak{so}_{4n}(\mathbb{C})$. Now, let $\phi_1:\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow\mathfrak{so}_{4n}(\mathbb{C})$ and $\phi_2:\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow\mathfrak{so}_{4n}(\mathbb{C})$ be Lie algebra maps satisfying $\phi_1(e)\in\mathcal{O}_1$ and $\phi_2(e)\in\mathcal{O}_2$. As discussed above, each map gives a representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ on $\mathfrak{so}_{4n}(\mathbb{C})$. These two representations are actually isomorphic. While $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ cannot be related by an inner automorphism of $\mathfrak{so}_{4n}(\mathbb{C})$ (as $\mathcal{O}_1\neq\mathcal{O}_2$), they are nevertheless related by a Lie algebra automorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REVISED VERSION: On further reflection, I think the answer to your question is always "yes" (if $\mathfrak{g}$ is *simple*, to avoid complications of the type Dave indicates).   At first I was confused by the example discussed in the question, but I think the main issue is how the automorphism group interacts with Dynkin diagrams of nilpotent orbits.

In the classical Dynkin-Kostant treatment of nilpotent orbits in a simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, the basic strategy is to embed a (nonzero) nilpotent element in a copy of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$.   Such an embedding isn't unique, but there is a resulting bijection between conjugacy classes of nilpotents (under the adjoint group of $\mathfrak{g}$) and conjugacy classes of such subalgebras.  In turn, the adjoint action of the subalgebra leads to a decorated *Dynkin diagram* (with vertices labelled $0, 1, 2$) which determines uniquely the given nilpotent orbit.   (Some references to textbooks by Carter and Collingwood-McGovern which include Dynkin diagrams are given in my old notes [here](http://people.math.umass.edu/~jeh/pub/D_4.pdf).)

In your type $D$ example, there are typically pairs of orbits interchanged by an outer automorphism of $\mathfrak{g}$ that comes from a graph automorphism.   These orbits have many common properties, and corresponding copies of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ do act equivalently on $\mathfrak{g}$ even though they lead to distinct Dynkin diagrams.   The key fact is that these Dynkin diagrams just involve a permutation of labels induced by the outer automorphism.  Only in such limited cases can two subalgebras of type $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ act equivalently in the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{g}$: this is clear from the determination of Dynkin diagrams for each $\mathfrak{g}$.

[Concerning terminology, it's fairly conventional to call two representations *equivalent* but the associated modules *isomorphic*.   The choice of either representation or module language is usually optional, at least in finite dimensional cases.]

Comment: Jim, the representations afforded by taking $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ to be root embeddings won't usually be isomorphic. For example, in type $B_2$, the adjoint representation for a short root decomposes into three isomorphic 3-dimensional irreducibles (plus a 1-dimensional trivial), but the adjoint representation for a long root has a 3-dimensional, two 2-dimensionals, and three 1-dimensionals. (Well, something like that, anyway.)

Comment: @Dave: I was just having some second thoughts, so I edited my answer.   I may still be oversimplifying.

Comment: When $\mathfrak{g}$ is simple, and we consider only root embeddings, I think your analysis is correct, except that we first have to eliminate cases where the representation corresponding to a long root is not isomorphic to the representation corresponding to a short root.  Extrapolating from $B_2$, I would think they are usually not isomorphic.

Comment: Jim, when you say the answer is always "yes", do you mean for the simple case? It's easy to cook up counterexamples for the non-simple case, because we just have to take make sure every weight of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ occurs the same number of times in the two representations.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, I'm only considering simple Lie algebras.   I've also tried to clarify my answer yet again but will give up edits at this point.

Answer (score 9):

No, here is a counterexample.

Let $\mathfrak{g}_1 = \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C}) \oplus \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C}) \oplus \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$, and let $\phi_1 \colon \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C}) \to \mathfrak{g}_1$ be the diagonal embedding, so $\phi(x) = (x,x,x)$. Then the representation obtained by composing $\phi_1$ with the adjoint representation is the direct sum of three $3$-dimensional irreducible modules.

Let $\mathfrak{g}_2 = \mathfrak{so}_5(\mathbb{C})$, and let $\phi_2$ be the embedding onto $\langle \mathfrak{u}_\alpha, \mathfrak{u}_{-\alpha} \rangle$, where $\alpha$ is a short root. Then the representation obtained by composing $\phi_2$ with the adjoint representation is the direct sum of a trivial representation and precisely three $3$-dimensional irreducible modules.

Now, if we let $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{g}_1 \oplus \mathfrak{g}_2$, then we can think of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ as homomorphisms into $\mathfrak{g}$ and, from the above, we see that their compositions with the adjoint representation are isomorphic. However, the image of $\phi_2$ is contained in the unique ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$ that is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{so}_5(\mathbb{C})$, but the image of $\phi_1$ is not contained in this ideal. So no element of $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ can take $\phi_1$ to $\phi_2$.

Comment: I am probably misreading something but it sounds like you say that if V denotes the direct sum of three 3-dimensional irreducible $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-modules then V is isomorphic to the direct sum of a trivial representation and V itself.  Given that the trivial representation is one-dimensional, how is this possible?

Comment: What I mean is that the representations of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ both contain three 3-dimensional irreducibles, and the rest of each representation is a big trivial module. Specifically, each is the direct sum of three 3-dimensional irreducibles and ten 1-dimensional trivial modules. So the two representations are isomorphic.

Comment: Thank you! This is exceedingly helpful. In light of the two given answers, I should probably require $\mathfrak{g}$ to be simple.