# Lie algebra action from the action of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-triple operators

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a complex simple Lie algebra and let $\{e,f,h\}$ be a $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-triple in $\mathfrak{g}$, i. e. we have commutation relations:
$$
[e,f]=h,~[h,e]=2e,~[h,f]=-2f.
$$
In particular, elements $\{e,f,h\}$ span a three-dimensional Lie subalgebra in $\mathfrak{g}$.

**Question.** Suppose that $\mathfrak{g}$ acts on some vector space $V$ and we know the actions of elements $e,f,h$ (so we know that $V$ **is** a representation of $\mathfrak{g}$). What "minimal" information we need in addition to this in order to restore the action of the whole algebra $\mathfrak{g}$? I think we can suppose that $e$, $f$, $h$ are regular elements of the algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. I am particularly interested in the case when $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{sl}_n$.

Of course, this question may not have a precise answer, but any help/references would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you given in advance that the action _does_ extend to $\mathfrak g$, or are you interested in determining _whether_ it extends?  (Also, are you working over $\mathbb C$?)

Comment: I think that [an example from @DaveWitteMorris](https://mathoverflow.net/a/201071) is relevant.

Comment: The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ could be a sum of some $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ and some arbitrary semisimple Lie algebra, with an arbitrary action on $V$.

Comment: @BenMcKay Indeed. I think we should restrict ourselves to the case of simple Lie algebra (actually, the initial motivation was about particular case $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{sl}_{n}$). I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: (Very rough musings so take with a pinch of salt). I'm going to assume we know what kind of representation it is (i.e. is it a single irrep or a sum of irreps of certain dimension etc.) . For high enough dimension this is not at all obvious. From there you'll at least need to know the action of the centraliser of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ since its action will commute. If it is regular this centraliser will be small (indeed I think it is just the orthocomplement of $h$ in the Cartan subalgebra it defines). I don't know if that is enough to fix the action though.

Comment: See the book Non-Abelian Harmonic Analysis by Roger Howe and Eng-Chye Tan.

Comment: @JeffreyAdams What exactly I should looking for? As far as I can see they are mostly working with real $\operatorname{SL}_2$.

Comment: @Callum The centraliser of a regular $\mathfrak{sl} _2$ in a simple Lie algebra is trivial. If $V$ is a simple ${\mathfrak g}$-module then it equals $L(\lambda)$ for some dominant weight $\lambda$, and the action of your regular $h$ tells you the height of $\lambda$. You also know the dimension of $V$, and there can't be too many possibilities for $\lambda$ given this information. However, the action of a regular $\mathfrak{sl} _2$ can't tell the difference between $V$ and $V^*$.